# What is the minimum allowed distance an AC breaker can be placed from the AC unit?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, air-conditioning

I have a separate external AC breaker box in the middle of a wall and I'd like to move the AC breaker box closer to the AC unit so I can do something unrelated with that wall.  I understand that the breaker needs to be readily accessible & within sight, but is there a minimum distance it must be away from the AC unit?  For example, can I place it behind the AC unit on the wall ~1 foot above the AC unit?  What about near the ground to the side of the AC unit?
I want the placement to be safe and code legal.  This is in California in case it matters.

Comment: Nitpick: *means of disconnect* must be less than fifty feet, accessible, and within sight. The *breaker* could be wherever. But it needs a convenience outlet at less than ten feet, and they sell disconnects w/ receptacles for that.

Comment: "Sec. 312.2, "In damp or wet locations, surface-type enclosures within the scope of this Article shall be placed or equipped so as to prevent moisture or water from entering and accumulating within the cabinet or cutout box, and shall be mounted so there is at least 1/4-in. airspace between the enclosure and the wall or other supporting surface." https://www.ecmweb.com/code-quiz-of-day/article/20899986/enclosures-installed-in-damp-and-wet-locations

Comment: If it's behind and facing the unit; three feet: the required working space for the disconnect. Code or not, you don't want it less than at least a foot from grade. Ideally it's on either side. Wherever, as long as you can stand in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

Any breaker panel needs working space.  This must be the width of the panel (but 30” minimum), 36” deep, and 78" tall.  With a flat surface to stand on, and with a viable path to get away from it.

This working space must be kept clear at ALL times.

Wherever you put it, you must provide this working space.  If the working space is not available there, it can't go there.

There's a maximum distance it can be from the A/C unit, but if you're moving it closer, that is not a factor.